# How could I know which bit-version of C++ program I'm building in VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

As the subject says, I'm building my C++ program in Visual Studio 2008.  But how could I know if the program built is targeted to 32-bit or 64-bit?  I looked around the project properties but couldn't find an option to specify this.

I looked at this article: [In Visual Studio, how to correctly build an application for 64-bit machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190842/in-visual-studio-how-to-correctly-build-an-application-for-64-bit-machines) But it looks like discussing about C# - I couldn't find any "Any CPU"-like configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open Visual Studio 2008
- Load your project
- Once your project is loaded, the VS2008 toolbar should look something like this:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 Toolbar]

- Drop down the list that says "Win32" and choose "Configuration Manager...".  This will open the Configuration Manager dialog:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 Configuration Manager Dialog]

- Under "Active Solution Platform", click the drop down list
- Select ""
- The "New Solution Platform" opens:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 New Solution Platform Dialog]

- Click on the top drop-down (labeled "Type or select the new platform:")
- One of the options, at the bottom of the list, should read "x64".  Select it.
- In the "Copy settings from:" drop-down, choose ""
- Check the "Create new project platforms" checkbox
- Press the "OK" button
- The New Solution Platform dialog closes, and now the x64 platform will be available for you to use in the Configuration Manager dialog.
- In the Configuration Manager dialog, for each project in your solution, choose the appropriate platform:

[image: Visual Studio 2008 Configuration Manager with x64 platform]

- Keep in mind that once you have the x64 platform added to Configuration Manager, you'll probably have to setup appropriate configurations (Release, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the details!  Where did you find this information?  Could you share me a link?  And I'm in fact more interested in the specific project properties in VS2008 which I need to set in order to build 32-/64-bit programs.  I see there is a "Detect 64-bit portability issues" option in "C++"-"General".  But I don't think it's a one that affects the build bit-version.

Comment: I know the information and created the sample screens from Visual Studio 2008, which I still have installed, though seldom use because I've migrated to Visual Studio 2012 a while back.  Please accept my answer if you believe it is correct.